# Can I boot a Live CD by mounting an ISO

Tags: boot, iso-image, livecd, kali-linux

I've just downloaded the Kali Linux (1.0.7) ISO and I was wondering if I can boot a Live CD by mounting an ISO to a virtual drive.

Can I boot it?

Answer (score 1):

No you can't do that, you need to burn ISO either on USB/External hard disk/DVD/CD to mount while booting. Because if you do that by mounting, Once it is restarted your reference to mounted drive will not be there. Though, you can use ISO to install OS inside virtual machine.

I'll recommend you to use VirtualBox/VMWare Player to run live CD on virtual machine.

Comment: Can I install an OS with just an ISO into a physical OS(no USB/CD/DVD)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install an OS from an ISO without the use of a USB/CD then you could look into [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)'s frugal install.

Download unetbootin, then run it and choose the hard drive you want to install on, reboot, then it should attempt to start the ISO.

Answer (score 0):

You can boot it using a bootable usb.

All you need is a 4gb usb and a linux machine. On a terminal of a linux machine, type

```
dd if=[filename] of=[device name] bs=4M
```

where iso file is your kali iso and the device is the device name of your usb. /dev/sda refers to your first hard disk drive so if you inserted a usb flash it will be /dev/sdb.
Run fdisk -l to identify what device is your usb.

So for example if your iso file is kali-linux-1.0.7.iso and your usb device is /dev/sdb,
the command should be like this.

```
dd if=kali-linux-1.0.7.iso of=/dev/sdb bs=4M
```

make sure you are in the same directory of your iso file in the terminal.

After that, on the BIOS select the usb to first boot and there you go.